# How can I parse the output from HostIP's geolocation API?

Tags: php, parsing, geolocation

If I access the HostIP geolocation API via http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=193.148.1.1,  it returns three lines of text:

```
Country: SPAIN (ES)
City: (Unknown city)
IP: 193.148.1.1
```

How can I parse that output in PHP to extract the country name?

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/409999/93732

Comment: not really, he has one, just needs a way to parse it. Though he should probably check that question (might already have an alternate solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these preg_matches

```
$info = "Country: SPAIN (ES)
City: (Unknown city)
IP: 193.148.1.1";

preg_match("/Country: (.*)\n/", $info, $out);
echo $out[1];

## OR
preg_match ("/Country: (.*) \(.*\)?\n/", $info, $out);
echo $out[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Would some regex for PHP help?

```
if (preg_match('/Country: (.*[^\n\r])/i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}

You will have: 

Match 1: Country: SPAIN (ES)
Group 1: SPAIN (ES)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain an XML response from hostip.info if you use the following URL:

`http://api.hostip.info/?ip=193.148.1.1`

instead of:

`http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=193.148.1.1`

Then, you can parse the XML which is kind of cleaner than Regex, and probably more immune to the possible changes of output formatting.

This is an example of parsing the output:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/?ip=193.148.1.1');

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXml($response);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);

$path = '/HostipLookupResultSet/gml:featureMember/Hostip/';

$ip = $xpath->evaluate($path . 'ip')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$city = $xpath->evaluate($path . 'gml:name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$countryName = $xpath->evaluate($path . 'countryName')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$countryAbbrev = $xpath->evaluate($path . 'countryAbbrev')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

country only: http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=193.148.1.1

Answer (score 0):

http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?position=true

{"country_name":"VENEZUELA","country_code":"VE","city":"Caracas","ip":"xxx.xx.xxx.xx","lat":"x.xxx","lng":"-xx.xxxx"}

Answer (score 0):

```
function _get_country_from_IP($ip) {
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
  return $country = isset($data->country) ? $data->country : 'UNKNOWN';
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments as to how your code answers the question.