# Geo targeting content using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ip-geolocation

I have a site for which i want to show a image in india only and for the rest of the world I will show some other image. This means, in India I want to show content for India only and for the remaining countries will show some other content. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the visiting users IP address, and track down his location and depending on his country you can show the custom pictures.

Some related questions:

[Getting the location from an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-location-from-ip-address)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service#364706

Here's a code snippet to detect the user location by their IP Address
(although the results arent much accurate)

```
function detect_city($ip) {

        $default = 'UNKNOWN';

        if (!is_string($ip) || strlen($ip) < 1 || $ip == '127.0.0.1' || $ip == 'localhost')
            $ip = '8.8.8.8';

        $curlopt_useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)';

        $url = 'http://ipinfodb.com/ip_locator.php?ip=' . urlencode($ip);
        $ch = curl_init();

        $curl_opt = array(
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER      => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT   => $curlopt_useragent,
            CURLOPT_URL       => $url,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 1,
            CURLOPT_REFERER         => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_opt);

        $content = curl_exec($ch);

        if (!is_null($curl_info)) {
            $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        if ( preg_match('{<li>City : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs) )  {
            $city = $regs[1];
        }
        if ( preg_match('{<li>State/Province : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs) )  {
            $state = $regs[1];
        }

        if( $city!='' && $state!='' ){
          $location = $city . ', ' . $state;
          return $location;
        }else{
          return $default; 
        }

}
```

Comment: He will of course also need to structure his content delivery to pick the right content for the right country. IP geolocation is not just enough.