# Get Country, GMT, City by IP address using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have tried to get the **Country**, **City**, and **GMT** using `js` by set it to cookies, and then I fetch it with `PHP` to save into `Database`.
But the method I used, is does not work sometimes,
So, is there anyway to get them by using PHP alone?
or is there another way by using JS?

I using this `js` provided by **maxmind**

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

But I often fail to save the data.

Comment: Please read this question my friend, I think its what your looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-location-from-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP GeoIP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) may help you

Comment: Module itself is free. GeoIP database has commercial one and free one.