# C# string assign

Tags: c#, ip, country-codes

My programm locates your IP Adress with country.
when you are from germany, it will display DE
when you are in USA it will display US
etc.

Now my question is how to turn automaticly the string maybe from HU to Hungary.
Should i create an itemlist or sth like that?

[image: Screenshot]

There you see, I'm getting the country information from a website http://api.hostip.info/country.php
You see above the Get IP button Country: DE and i want to change this automaticly in Germany

Comment: Probably a dictionary.  The full list is [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary and set the key to be your returned result with the value to be the desired country name.  Look here for a basic overview: [Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options for solving this issue:

- Build a `Dictionary<Country, string>`
- Use the `Country` enumeration and decorate it with a `Description` attribute

Build a `Dictionary<Country, string>`, like this:

```
enum Country
{
    UnitedStates,
    Germany,
    Hungary
}

Dictionary<Country, string> CountryNames = new Dictionary<Country, string>
{
    { Country.UnitedStates, "US" },
    { Country.Germany, "DE" }
    { Country.Hungary, "HU" }
};

static string ConvertCountry(Country country) 
{
    string name;
    return (CountryNames.TryGetValue(country, out name))
        ? name : country.ToString();
}
```

Now you can use the `Dictionary<Country, string>` via the static `ConvertCountry` method, like this:

```
var myCountry = ConvertCountry(Country.UnitedStates));
```

Use the `Country` enumeration and decorate it with a `Description` attribute, like this:

```
enum Country
{
    [Description("US")]
    UnitedStates,
    [Description("DE")]
    Germany,
    [Description("HU")]
    Hungary
}
```

Now you can use this method to get a `Description` attribute value, like this:

```
public static string GetDescription(Enum en)
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();

        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
            }
        }

        return en.ToString();
    }
```

Usage of above method, like this:

```
var myCountryDescription = GetDescription(Country.UnitedStates);
```

Comment: can you give me a liittllee example? :)

Comment: +1 great answer, @DiarDo copy the code and have a go its elegant the way it is, making it simpler would lose the elegance.

Comment: Don't they want the opposite of this?  They want to resolve "US" to "United States".

Answer (score 1):

You could create a object that relations the Short and the long country name using this   [table](http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/downloads/ip-to-country.csv.zip?XID=8c34f126740ee31c61b669dc2e60936f).

That´s also another post that answer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address)