# How I check ip address and ask security ans

Tags: php

i want to do if a person login from state A(this is his home town) and after 2 hours the same account login again by another state B. then ask a security Answer.

How i can check this. with the help of cookie or any thing else

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address

Comment: @Pekka웃 This isn't quite a duplicate.

Comment: @Brad the answer ends up being geolocation. It's arguably perfectly acceptable as an additional security measure. When a user logs in from the US, and then from Russia two hours later, it's prudent to ask a security question.

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's only part of it.  If it was simple geolocation, there would be no problem here.

Comment: @brad he's not trying to authenticate the user through geolocation. He's looking for clues when it might be prudent to ask a security question - how to detect possibly suspicious patterns. Using geolocation for that is perfectly acceptable practice and employed around the world. If you log in with a U.S. IP at noon, and with a Russian IP at two, something may be up. So you ask a security question. (Of course this needs to be done carefully - your example illustrates that. But you'll agree the average user doesn't have IPs from two continents at the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't check for this.  IP geolocation is not nearly accurate enough.

From my desk right now, I have 3 IP addresses.  One in Illinois, another in Missouri (cell phone provider has registered their IPs there), and a proxy server on a VPS in Europe.  In addition, it's common for addresses to change regularly.

Consider using two-factor authentication if you want to increase your security standards.