# Getting City/Place from IP Address

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-api

I have same issue as stated in

[Getting the location from an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address)

But I want to do in ASP.NET MVC4..

I believe I need to use below script...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
   contry_code = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code
   city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city
   region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region
 </script>
```

But how I will call from my controller. In my MVC controller, I get IP address as below:
string ipAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;

After that how will I pass my IP address to the script in controller and get the result from Google?

Comment: you could use ajax to post these values back to your controller, or perhaps a redirect with the parameters in a query string.

Comment: IP address is a horrible way of determining location. In a best case scenario the IP will be tied to a block held at a centralized location for the ISP, in which case you really only get an approximate region of a state or sometimes only a region among multiple states in the U.S. In a worst case scenario, the IP is through a proxy or frontend cache or the user is behind a VPN, in which case, you'd be luck to narrow it down to a correct country.

Comment: Use a web service to get the location information, e.g. http://www.ipinfodb.com