# Converting IP address to get location

Tags: tcp, ip

I want to check where is this ip ? but there is an problem , it appears like `213.158.175.75:80`

and when I check it like `213.158.175.75` it gives me a general location so my question is can

I use the `80` number to generate a new IP address that represent a accurate location ?`is it possible ?`

Comment: 80 is just the port number. By default, http=80; https=443.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the location from an IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address)

Comment: No. The number following the colon represents the TCP port of the application using the network connection. It has nothing to do with physical location or generating a 'new' IP address. That's like asking if I can figure out what car a person drives from their street address.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the 80 number is the port number and it's the default and it might be 443.