# How to get user-ip, location, country name, currency and time in PHP

Tags: php, html, geoip

I want the smallest possible code for this question. I never want to follow other questions as they never helped me and given me back to back errors

Comment: the question had been asked before , for reference see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address

Comment: Googling this would have led you to questions here where this has already been answered as well as links to the software you can use and tutorials on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting inappropriate results because maybe you are using a localhost server, try a hosting server , i got the same problem 3 months ago it worked fine when i tested on a hosting server.