# getting user city from IP Address using ip2location

Tags: php

I'm trying to get user city using ipaddress and for that I have found this
https://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-country-region-city

In the instruction is says "translate the IP address to an IP number in decimal format" but I don't know how .

This is my ip address : 5.219.212.240 , What should I do according to the instruction?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address

Comment: @WilliamCasey I don't want to use any online tools . I'm trying to make It offline and This is what I have found .

Comment: If you searched the FAQ from this website you would have found what you were looking for: https://lite.ip2location.com/faqs "How do I convert a IP Address to a IP Number?"

Comment: @jedgar look at my answer bellow

Answer (score 2):

Well I [think](https://www.countryipblocks.net/ip-address-conversion-to-decimal-and-binary-equivalents) this is what documentation refers to. Here is an example from the link:

> Calculating the decimal value of an IPv4 address is easy. If we were
>   to number the octets from left to right and break them into variables
>   called $octet1, $octet2, $octet3 and $octet4, we can use the following
>   formulas to convert each octet into its decimal value and then add
>   each decimal value to achieve the decimal equivalent for the IP
>   address:
>
> $octet1 x (256^3) = $decimal1
>
> $octet2 x (256^2) = $decimal2
>
> $octet3 x (256) = $decimal3
>
> $octet4 = $decimal4
>
> $decimal1 + $decimal2 + $decimal3 + $decimal4 = $decimal_equivalent
>
> For example, converting IP Address 192.168.1.16 to its decimal
>   equivalent would look like this:
>
> 192 x (256^3) = 3221225472
>
> 168 x (256^2) = 11010048
>
> 1 x 256 = 256
>
> 16 = 16
>
> 3221225472 + 11010048 + 16 = 3232235792
>
> The decimal equivalent of 192.168.1.16 is 3232235792.