# How to locate the IP address in mtr

Tags: networking, ip

While I use [mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) to do a network diagnostic(traceroute/ping/etc.) I must copy and paste the IP address to google the real location(like city,region,country)

Can I get the location of the IP address using some database?

Is there any package?

Answer (score 0):

GeoIP database.

Most languages have a wrapper (either 1st- or 3rd-party) so you don't need to work with the DB directly, e.g.

- JavaScript: https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/
- Python: https://pythonhosted.org/python-geoip/
- Ruby: https://github.com/cjheath/geoip

See also: [Getting the location from an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

as an option: mtr from fork with extra ip address info, for example from this fork
https://github.com/yvs2014/mtr085
with `mtr -y5,5,4,1 targethost`
you will get `City Region Country Host ...stats` in output